# Rails, Bootstrap and Devise Navbar Login: How to get login details on same line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I know how to put all the details on the same line via css, but the css placement seems to break my code.

Specifically, I am not sure where to put this line of code:
 
`<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">`

Here is the **code that works** and lets me sign in correctly, but the css is not as I like (it looks odd because it is missing the css line I mentioned earlier):

```
<% else %>                
                <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

                  <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email address', :class => "form-control" %>             

                  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password', :class => "form-control" %>

                  <%=f.submit 'Sign In', :class => 'btn btn-default'%>

                  <div class="txt-right">
                     <input type="checkbox"> Remember me

  <a href="#" class="forgot"><i>Forgot your password?</i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="forgot"><i>Sign Up</i></a>
                  </div>   
                <% end %>

          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

The above CSS looks like this. 
[image]

Here is code that **does not work**, but looks better CSS-wise -

```
<% else %>


                <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

                  <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email address', :class => "form-control" %>             

                  <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password', :class => "form-control" %>

                  <%=f.submit 'Sign In', :class => 'btn btn-default'%>

                  <div class="txt-right">
                     <input type="checkbox"> Remember me

  <a href="#" class="forgot"><i>Forgot your password?</i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="forgot"><i>Sign Up</i></a>
                  </div>               
                <% end %>            
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

The above CSS looks like so *(I'll fix the "forgot pass?" text later, not sure how to do right now)*

- [image]

---

Resources:

Entire application.html.erb file - 
https://gist.github.com/attatae/11016882
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

(Here is a similar question but it did not really help me. Possibly I "missed" something but I've trying for a while with no luck.) [Rails Login with Twitter Bootstrap Navbar (w/ Devise)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079845/rails-login-with-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-w-devise)

Comment: And how exactly is css placement breaking your code? Do you get any error? If yes, then please share the relevant error log.

Comment: Hi @Kirti, the code that has better css, but will not log in, simply refreshes the page, and everything looks normal (except that I am not logged in.) Also, the URL says this: `http://localhost:3000/?utf8=%E4%9C%93&authenticity_token=VPSQB5F0GQDjiK1DkP84y3IAU6mM7h0eDWiXUcTIZmo%3D&user[email]=example%40gmail.com&user[password]=mypassword&commit=LOGIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form_for` method will already create the `<form>` element, so there's no need to include it (as you have in your Gist).

Remove the highlighted line:
https://gist.github.com/attatae/11016882#file-application-html-erb-stackov-L52

And change the `form_for` call to look like

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => 'navbar-form navbar-right' }) do |f| %>
```

This just tells the `form_for` method to include the necessary CSS classes on the `<form>` tag it will automatically generate.